# How to remove documents in mongodb that haven't updated in the last 24hrs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've a mongodb collection called collection_a and I update it's documents regulary, but sometimes the data returned from my backend only onclude some of the documents in this collection.

What I want is that any document that hasn't been updated in the last 24 hrs, it's removed automaticly.

What I've tried to do is the following :-

1- I created an index called createdAt and added expiresAfterSeconds on it

`createdAt: { type: Date, expires: 86400, default: Date.now() },`

but this removed the document after 24hrs even if it was updated.

my 2nd solution was as follow

2- create a field in my collection Schema called timestamp as follows

`timestamp: { type: Number, default: Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) },`

and add the following code after bulkUpdate

PS the data has timestamp field in it `timestamp: Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000),`

```
let upserts = data.map((doc) => ({
  updateOne: {
    filter: { coin: doc.coin },
    update: doc,
    upsert: true,
  },
}));

await CollectionAModel.bulkWrite(upserts);

let _collection_a_documents = await CollectionAModel.find({});
let _collection_a_documents_gt_24hrs = [];

for (let i = 0; i < _collection_a_documents.length; i++) {
  const _collection_a_document = _collection_a_documents[i];

  let tsNow = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
  let tsDiff = tsNow - _collection_a_document.timestamp;

  if (tsDiff > 24 * 3600) {
    _collection_a_documents_gt_24hrs.push(_collection_a_document);
  }
}

await CollectionAModel.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: _collection_a_documents_gt_24hrs.map((el) => el._id) } });
```

but still the solution doesn't work

Is there any method, to make mongo delete documents that doesn't update if a certain time passed without updating that document?

Comment: YourModel.find({ updatedAt: { $lt: twentyFourHoursAgo } }, (err, documents) => { /**/ });

Comment: what do you mean by twentyFourHoursAgo, I store the field in document as timestamp `Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);` so I can't say $lt 24hrs

Comment: `const twentyFourHoursAgo.setHours(new Date().getHours() - 24);`

Comment: in order to say in mongodb $lt: hours, on a field using timestamp will not work, you can't use your solution, and how is your solution different than just getting the timestamp difference and checking if it's more 24hrs like my 2nd solution

Comment: "_but this removed the document after 24hrs even if it was updated_" - how about putting the TTL index on an `updatedAt` field that gets modified when the document is written to? Can add the modification logic in a pre hook if using mongoose. This is literally what TTL indexes are for, you just need to make sure that the values in the documents for the TTL field are updated and set to the appropriate value

Comment: so basiclly by updateding createdAt field with the new values, the index expiresAfterSeconds get updated as well ?

Comment: @user20042973  I quote from mongodb docs the following "TTL indexes are special single-field indexes that MongoDB can use to automatically remove documents from a collection after a certain amount of time or at a specific clock time. Data expiration is useful for certain types of information like machine generated event data, logs, and session information that only need to persist in a database for a finite amount of time." ---- this means that it will expire after a time even if it was updated my friend, your solution is wrong

Comment: It's not that the _definition_ of the index changes (eg the value of `expiresAfterSeconds`). Rather it's that the time is dynamically calculated for each document  where that value is part of it. From the [Behavior section of the same docs page](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-ttl/#expiration-of-data) (emphasis added): "_the expiration threshold is **the indexed field value** plus the specified number of seconds._" Have you given it a try? Yes you can update the value of `createdAt` though that would seemingly negate the purpose of that field based on its name?

Comment: @user20042973 I'll give it a try and tell you the results